# Which mobs can spawn on snow-covered ground?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can pigs and other animals spawn on snow-covered dirt? Can creepers and other monsters spawn on snow-covered blocks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Snow coverage does not affect spawning at all. To be more precise, mobs will spawn as if blocks of snow-cover are blocks of air.

Answer (score 3):

Grave digging this bad boy as it was a question I was looking for an answer for just now, [mobs won't spawn when there are 2-7 layers of snow](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Snow#Trivia)

Answer (score -5):

Snow Golems, but they don't attack players. :(

.

.